# How to bash multithread?

Tags: bash, multithreading

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="," read  ip port; do
    ruby test.rb "http://$ip:$port/"&
    ruby test.rb "https://$ip:$port/";
 done <test1.txt
```

How would i do this multithreading?
if i do more lines divided by & it only runs the same command with the same ip&port more times, i want it to run with next ip&port nor the same
the file looks like 
192.168.1.2,8089,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tr ',' ':' <test1.txt | xargs -P 4 -I XX ruby test.rb "http://XX/"
```

Assuming that the `test1.txt` file contains lines like

```
127.0.0.1,80
127.0.0.1,8080
```

then the `tr` would change this to

```
127.0.0.1:80
127.0.0.1:8080
```

and the `xargs` would take a line at a time and replace `XX` in the given command string with the contents of the line and run the command.  With `-P 4` we get at most four simultaneous processes running.

If your file has trailing commas on each line, remove them first:

```
sed 's/,$//' test1.txt | tr ',' ':' | xargs ...as above...
```

or even

```
sed -e 's/,$//' -e 'y/,/:/' test1.txt | xargs ...as above...
```

Comment: http://192.168.1.2:80:/ There is an extra ":" where dows that come from? crap, i have the file like this 192.168.1.2,80,

Comment: @Killroy2018 I had to guess the format of the text file since you did not mention what was in it. You either have trailing commas or colons in the file.

Comment: @Killroy2018 See updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

I would do it this way:

```
parallel --colsep , ruby test.rb {3}://{1}:{2}/ :::: ipport.txt ::: http https
```

It will default to run one job per cpu core. This can be adjusted with `-j20` for 20 jobs in parallel.

Contrary to the `xargs`-solution you can post process the output: The output is serialized, so you will never see output from two jobs mix.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

For security reasons it is recommended you use your package manager to
install. But if you cannot do that then you can use this 10 seconds
installation.

The 10 seconds installation will try to do a full installation; if
that fails, a personal installation; if that fails, a minimal
installation.

```
$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || lynx -source pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || \
   fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3 ) > install.sh
$ sha1sum install.sh | grep 883c667e01eed62f975ad28b6d50e22a
12345678 883c667e 01eed62f 975ad28b 6d50e22a
$ md5sum install.sh | grep cc21b4c943fd03e93ae1ae49e28573c0
cc21b4c9 43fd03e9 3ae1ae49 e28573c0
$ sha512sum install.sh | grep da012ec113b49a54e705f86d51e784ebced224fdf
79945d9d 250b42a4 2067bb00 99da012e c113b49a 54e705f8 6d51e784 ebced224
fdff3f52 ca588d64 e75f6033 61bd543f d631f592 2f87ceb2 ab034149 6df84a35
$ bash install.sh
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

Download the cheat sheet: http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/parallel_cheat.pdf

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: Can someone let me know why this answer gets down-voted?

Comment: I guess someone downvote because find this description complicated) and indeed using gnu parallel requires reading it manual, while using xargs -P option requires almost nothing) but in all cases when you have tasks with uneven execution times (and accessing web sites especially with mix or protocols http and https is one of them) gnu parallel really helps you to organise tasks more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

`gnu-parallel` and `xargs` are much better options, but for the sake of demonstrating how to do it with the while loop, there are two major options that I see:

Do *everything* at the same time:

```
while IFS="," read  ip port; do
    ruby test.rb "http://$ip:$port/" <&- &
done <test1.txt
```

Limit yourself to 2 at a time:

```
while IFS="," read  ip port; do
    ruby test.rb "http://$ip:$port/" <&- &
    IFS=, read ip port || break
    ruby test.rb "http://$ip:$port/" <&- &
    wait
done <test1.txt
```

The second is less than ideal, as you will have dead time between the completion of one process and the completion of the second, and that problem grows worse as you add more processes.  You can attempt to fix that in the shell, but since `xargs` and `parallel` already exist, there's not much point.